# How to separate variables to other files and access

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I'm new in swift and IOS, I have no idea to separate the variable(mylessons) to other file(.swift) or (.json) to achieve MVC. Anyone can teach me? Thanks a lot

```
class LessonsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var mylessons = [["title":"Posture", "subtitle":"Set up your body",
"bgimage":"Ln1", "lesimage":"Posture_pic", "lestitle":"So starting from 
the head and moving down:", "lescontent":"1) The top back part of your 
head should be pointing up.."], ..]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
..
}
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve? i.e wha't the purpose of the separation?

Comment: Because the variable is too long, so I want to open a new file to store it and access it. whatever the new file is .swift or .json. Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest to create a *model* for the given object, your array should contains objects of this model instead of `[String: String]`.

Comment: Sorry, could you teach me more details? thank you so much

Comment: Please check my answer :) shoot me a comment if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to your given code snippet, for achieving [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html), you should create a model for the *lesson* -which contains the desired properties-, thus, `mylessons` array should contains objects of *lesson*.

If you want to separate the layers in different files (which is a good idea), you might want to create a file -`Lesson.swift` for example-, which contains your model, as follows:

**Lesson.swift:**

```
// Note that I decalred it as 'struct'
// instead of 'class' do what is suitable
// for your requirements...
struct Lesson {
    var title:String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var bgImage: String?
    var lesImage: String?
    var lesTitle: String?
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
// note that myLessons data type is: '[Lesson]'
var myLessons =  [Lesson(title: "Posture",
                         subtitle: "Set up your body",
                         bgImage: "Ln1",
                         lesImage: "Posture_pic",
                         lesTitle: "So starting from the head and moving down",
                         lesContent: "1) The top back part of your head should be pointing up..")]
```

*Remark: if you are implementing `table​View:​cell​For​Row​At​Index​Path:​`, you should access the lesson for each row like this:*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //....

    let currentLesson = myLessons[indexPath.row]

    // ...
}
```

---

**Also:**

It would be nice if you are able to convert the given dictionary to a lesson object, actually it is possible, by adding the following *Dictionary Extension*:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    func toLesson() -> Lesson {
        var lessonToRetrun = Lesson()

        if let title = self["title"] as? String {
            lessonToRetrun.title = title
        }

        if let subtitle = self["subtitle"] as? String {
            lessonToRetrun.subtitle = subtitle
        }

        if let bgimage = self["bgimage"] as? String {
            lessonToRetrun.bgImage = bgimage
        }

        if let lesimage = self["lesimage"] as? String {
            lessonToRetrun.lesImage = lesimage
        }

        if let lestitle = self["lestitle"] as? String {
            lessonToRetrun.lesTitle = lestitle
        }

        if let lescontent = self["lescontent"] as? String {
            lessonToRetrun.lesContent = lescontent
        }

        return lessonToRetrun
    }
}
```

you will be able to do:

```
let lessonDict = ["title":"Posture",
                  "subtitle":"Set up your body",
                  "bgimage":"Ln1", "lesimage":"Posture_pic",
                  "lestitle":"So starting from the head and moving down:",
                  "lescontent":"1) The top back part of your head should be pointing up.."]

let convertedLesson = lessonDict.toLesson()

print(convertedLesson)
// Lesson(title: Optional("Posture"), subtitle: Optional("Set up your body"), bgImage: Optional("Ln1"), lesImage: Optional("Posture_pic"), lesTitle: Optional("So starting from the head and moving down:"), lesContent: Optional("1) The top back part of your head should be pointing up.."))
```

but you have to be *pretty sure* that the `keys` are identical.

Hope this helped.